# How To Pass return false to my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this and i am doing conditional check like so:

```
function animateMenuWidth() {

     if($('.nav ul ul a').css('width')=='100px'){
     return false; 
     }
//do animate some stuff
}
```

This works fine as expected (not executing if the width is 100px).

Now my question is how can do the same check with reusing my if statment?

This will not work but illustrates my attempt:

```
function widthCheck(){

     if($('.nav ul ul a').css('width')=='100px'){
     return false;
     }

}
     function animateMenuWidth() {

      widthCheck(); //Return False is Ignored Here :(
     //do animate some stuff
     }
```

Comment: ***This works fine as expected*** are you sure? I don't think `css('width')` will return some value of `%`, it will be some value of `px`.

Comment: *"//Return False is Ignored Here :("* You are not doing anything with the return value. What do you expect to happen? Returning from a function doesn't return from the function that calls it. That would make composition more complicated.

Comment: LoL you are right it does return px values i meant "return false works fine as expected" aka not executing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function animateMenuWidth() {
    widthCheck() || return; // :)
   //do animate some stuff
}
```

So that you don't get into issues if `undefined` is returned by `widthCheck`, I would suggest the following tweak

```
function widthCheck(){    
    if($('.nav ul ul a').css('width')=='100px'){
        return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
 function animateMenuWidth() {

      if(widthCheck()) //Return False is Ignored Here :(
      {
     //do animate some stuff
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can one-liner this like so:

```
if (!widthCheck()) return false;
```

Just pop that into where you currently have `widthCheck()` and you should be good.